# jqGrid - cell data dispappears after sorting

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm generating a jqGrid table in which each cell displays data from multiple data elements.  For example the first column of each row contains name, group, subgroup, and personId, each displayed on a new line.  Each of these data elements are part of the jsonstring I pass in from the server.  Example data:

```
{"rows":[
  {
    "name":"Barnes, Bill Alan",
    "group":"11111",
    "subgroup":"11",
    "personId":"050"
  }]
}
```

I'm also setting datatype: `jsonstring`, `gridview: true`, `loadonce: true`

The table loads fine initially, but when I sort the table, the group, subgroup, and personId data elements are displayed as `undefined`.  I'm using a custom formatter to format the display and when I step thru that code I see the third param (I named it rowObject) doesn't contain the group, subgroup, or personId data like it did on initial load.

My formatter function:

```
function col1Formatter(value, options, rowObject) {
    return rowObject.name + "<br/>" + 
           rowObject.roster + "<br/>" +
           rowObject.subroster + "<br/>" +
           rowObject.personId 
}
```

My colModel (just the first column):

```
colModel: [{
  label: "Group", 
  name: "name", 
  width: 100, 
  classes:"tablecell_middle errorResultsCol_line", 
  formatter: col1Formatter}],
  ...
```

Hope that's enough information to answer this question:  why am I losing the roster, subroster, personId when I sort the table?

JSFiddle example.  I don't have any of the css styling applied to this example, but if you click on one of the column headers after the grid loads you will see many of the data elements become "undefined":  https://jsfiddle.net/6Ljyt0oh/29/

Comment: You should provide the demo, which reproduces the problem. You can create it in JSFiddle for example.

Comment: Updated with link to JSFiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the JSFiddle example don't work at all, The code is very very dirty. You defined `formatter` in all columns, but you don't defined neither `unformat` nor `sorttype` or `sortfunc`. It means that you informs jqGrid how to display the data, but not how to get the data back and how to sort there.

**You should never define `formatter` without unformatter (`unformat` callback). Moreover I would recommend you to use `datatype: "local"` instead of `datatype: "jsonstring"`**. It makes all properties of initial data be permanently available in the local data. It will simplify sorting of data.

You use commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) 5.0.2. I develop alternative fork of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) in the current version 4.12.1. I know only the functionality of free jqGrid and the functionality of old jqGrid (till the version 4.7). For example free jqGrid allows to specify `sortfunc` for the column which have the parameters `a, b, direction, aItem, bItem`, where `aItem` and `bItem` are *full compared items*. It allows very easy to specify custom sorting functions for every input data. Look [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/sortfunc.htm), which loads the data with many custom properties and sorts the data based on the values of the custom properties. [Another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/filterByAdditionalPropertiesAndSearchingDialog1.htm) shows how one can use Searching Dialog with the custom properties holding no hidden columns with the properties.

Comment: Thanks for all of the feedback.  I've been working with jqGrid for a short time and not finding a lot of good doco on correct way to use it.  Been relying mostly on examples.  I don't think I've seen any examples which use unformat callback. Maybe I'm not paying close enough attention.  I will look at converting to your free jqGrid.  Greatly appreciate all of your effort to maintain and help debug the plugin!  Also, my JSFiddle seems to work fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome or IE.  Issue seems to be with the source code repository I'm pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the initial time through, the calls to the formatters are provided the JSON values for the row. After sorting, the data passed through the formatter appears to be just the text values in each row, based on the column model's `name` attribute.

I tried `datatype: "local"` and tried adding an unformatter, and neither worked for me (`local` caused a blank screen, and the unformatter was never called). I've seen Unformatters called during editing though.

In my case, I was using a row variable containing a URL to format and build a link in that cell. Initially it worked, but after sorting, the row variable containing the URL is not in the rowObject parameter when the formatter was called.  Here's the solution that worked for me, `allRecords` is a variable containing the JSON string that contains the list of row data that is passed through the first time. The initial call doesn't have `rowObject._id_`, so it's undefined. After a sort, it contains the id (one-based row index by default) which I used to get the original rowObject's value. This `_id_` is fixed per row based on the original sorting, so sorting it doesn't change the value for the same row, which is helpful in this case.

```
table.jqGrid({
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            datastr: allRecords,
            ...

function urlFormatter(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
    //Fix for sorting issue
    if (rowObject._id_ != undefined) {
        //For after sorting, we lose the original data, get it back from the original
        rowObject = allRecords[rowObject._id_ -1];
    }

    //Original function
    if (typeof cellValue === 'undefined') {
        return '';
    } else if ((cellValue == "") || (rowObject.URL == "null")) {
        return cellValue;
    } else {
        return "<a href='" + rowObject.URL + "'>" + cellValue + "</a>";
    }
}
```